# [Symfony2][SwiftMailer] You have requested a non-existent parameter "sender_name"

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I installed a new [bundle](https://github.com/wasinger/jsonrpc-bundle) to my project in symfony2 and now swiftmailer returns an error.

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "sender_name".

```
Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: %mailer_transport%
host:      %mailer_host%
encryption: %mailer_encryption%
username:  %mailer_user%
password:  %mailer_password%
spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: please post the code where you try to send the email, probably you need to add the `sender_name` key in a parameter files as example the `parameter.yml`

Comment: Is all perfect added in parameters.yml

Comment: and if you remove the bundle it works fine?

Comment: Yes, but i must have this bundle...

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a `sender_name` parameter in your parameters.yml
and in your config.yml add

```
swiftmailer:
    sender_name: %sender_name%
```

Comment: This not work:
Unrecognized option "sender_name" under "swiftmailer.mailers.default"

Comment: Ok, can you try to set it manually before sending the email, using this example `->setFrom(array('addresss@email.com'=>'sender name'))`?

Comment: Where i must to add this? (Localization file)

Comment: when you create your message `$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom(…)`, in whatever file you are making the call to swiftmailer

Comment: Where is the file where exist "swiftmailer.mailers.default"

Comment: I don't think this exists, it's probably a configuration that looks like (in yml)
`swiftmailer:
    mailers:
        default`

Comment: Error results, add to parameters omitting config.

Comment: can you post the code where you try to send an email?